# Using Knp paginator on symfony 2.3 with weird controller

Tags: php, symfony, pagination, knppaginator, knppaginatorbundle

I'm using Knp paginator on a symfony 2.3 project and the project is new to me so the controllers are a bit odd to use.

I'm trying to install it but there is things that still blocks from making it functioning.

I'm following this [tutorial actually](https://codereviewvideos.com/course/pagination-filtering-and-sorting/video/pagination-with-twig-and-knppaginatorbundle)

and here is my code in my controller

```
private function resultsAction(Request $request, User $user, $type, $archive)
{
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

     $results = $em->getRepository("randomRepo")->findByTypeAndPro($type, $user, $archive);

     /**
      * @var $paginator \Knp\Component\Pager\Paginator
      */
     $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
     $results = $paginator->paginate(
         $results,
         $request->query->getInt('page',1),
         $request->query->getInt('limit',5)
     );


     return array("results" => $results, "archive" => $archive);
}

public function offerAction(User $user, $archive = false)
{
     return $this->resultsAction($user, Operation::OFFER, $archive);
}
```

My namespace and class using:

```
namespace ST\BackofficeBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use ST\UserBundle\Entity\Operation;
use ST\UserBundle\Entity\User;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

And so when I try to load my page I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Can you show your namespace and classes using?

Comment: Hi @ImanaliMamadiev I updated the post with namespace and classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add Request argument into ResultsAction call.

Declaration contains 4 arguments:

```
resultsAction(Request $request, User $user, $type, $archive)
```

Call contains 3:

```
public function offerAction(User $user, $archive = false)
{
    return $this->resultsAction($user, Operation::OFFER, $archive);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass Request class when you call action:

```
public function offerAction(Request $request, User $user, $archive = false)
{
    return $this->resultsAction($request, $user, Operation::OFFER, $archive);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I accepted svgrafov one. but thank you for your help